# How to display the first row of results from extracted data?

Tags: java, csv, array-map

I used the following script to read a CSV file and extract suspicious data in descending order. I am trying to print out the result of the highest occurrence which is the first result showing. Should I specify it in the map script? Can I utilize `println` to show that?

```
public class Part2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner csvData = new Scanner(
                new File("C:\\Users\\amber\\Documents\\IN300_Dataset1.csv"))) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (csvData.hasNext()) {
                list.add(csvData.nextLine());
                
            }
            String[] tempArray = list.toArray(new String[1]);
            String[][] csvArray = new String[tempArray.length][];
            
            String combined_list[] = new String[tempArray.length];
            
            String myData = null;
            
            for(int i=0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
                if(i == 0) continue;
                csvArray[i] = tempArray[i].split(",");
                if(csvArray[i][4].matches("^\"[a-zA-Z].*\"")) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    myData= csvArray[i][2] + " " +
                            csvArray[i][3] + " " +
                            csvArray[i][4] + " " +
                            csvArray[i][5] + " " +
                            csvArray[i][6]; 
                    combined_list[i] = myData;
                }
            }
            getOccurences("Suspicious Result(s)", combined_list);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private static void getOccurences(String message, String[] myArray) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (String key : myArray) {
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                int occurrence = map.get(key);
                occurrence++;
                map.put(key, occurrence);
            } else {
                map.put(key, 1);
            }
        }
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap =
                map.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
        
        printMap(message, sortedMap);
    }
    
    private static void printMap(String message, Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Printing" + message);
        System.out.println();
        
        map.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if(key != null && value > 100) {
                System.out.println(key + "appeared " + value + " times(s).");
            }
        });
    }
                
}
```

Here is a sample of my results (The bold text is the result that I only want to display):

PrintingSuspicious Result(s)

> **00:28:00:01:00:00 02:00:00:00:45:00 0x4006 44 Ethernet IIappeared 7536 times(s).**
> 209.99.61.21 192.168.1.24 UDP 1359 17212  >  52797 Len=1309appeared 2990 times(s).
> 192.168.1.24 209.99.61.21 UDP 170 52797  >  17212 Len=128appeared 2905 times(s).
> 209.99.61.21 192.168.1.24 UDP 1351 17212  >  52797 Len=1309appeared 2851 times(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only the first result, just quit the loop after displaying the first element (you'll have to use normal `for` loop instead of using `forEach` to be able to `break`):

```
private static void printMap(String message, Map<String, Integer> map)
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Printing" + message);
    System.out.println();
    
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      if (entry.getKey() != null && entry.getValue() > 100) {
          System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "appeared " + entry.getValue() + " times(s).");
          break;
      }
    }
}
```